# How can I have a group of different child class objects sharing one static variable of the base class from another group?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I got a lot of help here and this is the first time I ask questions so forgive me if I make any silly mistakes. Thanks!

I have a base class called `Car` in which there is a static variable for the derived class to share. e.g.

```
class Car {
    static int mileage;
}
```

Then I have a series of child classes for the different components of the car, such as `engine`, `wheel`, `body` ... they all share/modify the information of `mileage`.
The whole project may have several objects of `Car` and each of the `Car` object needs to contain a set of components of `engine`, `wheel`, `body` ... So my question is how to declare/define all these objects. Or what is the other way to realize the idea?

To be simple, how to make `Engine eng_car1; Wheel whe_car1; Body bod_car1;` share one `static int mileage` and  `Engine eng_car2; Wheel whe_car2; Body bod_car2;` share another `static int mileage`?

Thanks again!

Comment: Considering that different cars have different mileage, having that variable being `static` makes no sense. Neither does having the different parts of a car being actual "child classes" of `Car` (i.e. inheriting from `Car`). A car *contains* several parts (like engine, wheels, etc.) but the parts are not themselves cars.

Answer (score 1):

I'll neglecting the fact that you, for some reason, want to make the mileage `static`. Having all vehicles in a category *share* the same mileage value is an odd requirement. But I'll assume that you want a solution for a more applicable property.

One way to achieve your aim is to *templatise* `Car` and have two specialisations:

```
template <int N> struct Car;

template<> struct Car<1>
{
    static int mileage;
};

template<> struct Car<2>
{
    static int mileage;
};
```

You could replace 1 and 2 with enumerations to help readability. Or use `typedef`s.

The advantage of this approach is that the two instantiations will each get their own `mileage`; which is what you want.

Then, inherit from `Car<1>` or `Car<2>` as appropriate. If you need to, you could have the templates inheriting from a common base class.

Don't forget to reserve *storage* for both `static`s in exactly one compilation unit, else you'll get link-time errors.